# Как подсчитать каждый количество элементов всех дочерних массивов?

Tags: php

Есть такой массив

```
array(1) {
  ["one"]=>
  array(4) {
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Test"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "Test"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "Test"
    ["two"]=>
    array(2) {
      [1]=>
      string(4) "Test"
      [2]=>
      string(4) "Test"
    }
  }
}
```

Нужно чтобы он стал таким

```
array(1) {
  ["one"]=>
  array(5) {
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Test"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "Test"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "Test"
    ["count"]=>
    int(5)
    ["two"]=>
    array(3) {
      [1]=>
      string(4) "Test"
      [2]=>
      string(4) "Test"
      ["count"]=>
      int(2)
    }
  }
}
```

Прошу помогите!!!
Массив может достигать 8 уровней вложенности

Comment: А чем помочь - советом?

Comment: Да алгоритм какой хотябы)

Comment: Рекурсия в помощь

Comment: а ты уверен, что тебе именно это надо? не поделишься конечной задачей?

Comment: Конечная задача это отчет по лидам по каналам каналы имеют вложенности. По аналогии как сделано в Roistat. https://prnt.sc/qdnknz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = [
  'qwe',
  'qwe',
  'qwe',
  [
    'qwe',
    'qwe'
  ]
];

function setCount(&$arr){
    if (!is_array($arr))
        return;
    $arr['count'] = 0;
    $arr['count'] = count($arr);
    foreach($arr as &$child){
        if (is_array($child))
            setCount($child);
    }
}

setCount($arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

У вас в примере количество учитывает и сам елемент `count` - если нужно чтоб не считало `$arr['count'] = count($arr);` отнимите единицу